# Use MRJOB to count bigram: accur type error

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce, cpu-word, mrjob

I am a newcomer using map-reduce program with Mrjob. I need to use Mrjob to count bi-grams.

Here is my code:

```
import mrjob
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re
from itertools import islice, izip
import itertools

WORD_RE = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')

class BigramCount(MRJob):
  OUTPUT_PROTOCOL = mrjob.protocol.RawProtocol

  def mapper(self, _, line):
    words = WORD_RE.findall(line)

    for i in izip(words, islice(words, 1, None)):
      bigram=str(i[0]+"-" +i[1])
      yield (bigram, 1)

  def combiner(self, bigram, counts):
    yield (bigram.encode('utf-8'), sum(counts))

  def reducer(self, bigram, counts):
    yield (bigram.encode('utf-8'), sum(counts))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  BigramCount.run()
```

Then the error occurs:

```
return b'\t'.join(x for x in (key, value) if x is not None)

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, int found
```

Can anyone tells me what's wrong with my code? And how to debug it?

Comment: Please post either the full stacktrace of the error or the full code, I cannot see any line with `join` in your code

Comment: Fixed code indentation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I see the reason now, in my reducer,  I should yield (bigram.encode('utf-8'), str(sum(counts))) instead of just sum(counts) because I am writing the result to a file.